# Pass Type As Variable And Then Compare To Objects Type

Tags: c#, .net

I need to be able to pass a Type into a function and then compare the type to an objects type.

When I use code that i think i need to use, an error occurs.

> "A constant value is expected"

An example of this code without using the Type in a variable is.

```
object lComObject = "this is a string";
if (lComObject is String)
{
    ;
}
```

and and what im needing to do is

```
bool CompareObjectType(Type type_variable) {

    object lComObject = "this is a string";
    if (lComObject is type_variable)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }

}

CompareObjectType(typeof(string));
```

How do I pass a type as a variable while also being able to compare it to another objects type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the basis that the type to compare to is known at compile time:

```
CompareObjectType(typeof(string));
```

Then you should make your method generic:

```
bool CompareObjectType<T>()
{
    object lComObject = "this is a string";
    return lComObject is T;
}
```

And call like so:

```
CompareObjectType<string>();
```

---

If the type is only known at runtime, you would need to check the type of `lComObject` at runtime also using `GetType()`.

To emulate `is`-like behaviour, you could use `Type.IsAssignableFrom()`:

```
bool CompareObjectType(Type type_variable)
{
    object lComObject = "this is a string";
    return type_variable.IsAssignableFrom(lComObject.GetType());
}
```

And call like this:

```
CompareObjectType(someOtherObject.GetType());
CompareObjectType(typeof(string));
```

Answer (score 1):

Make it a generic type parameter instead.

```
void Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine(CompareObjectType<string>());
}

// Define other methods and classes here
bool CompareObjectType<T>() {

    object lComObject = "this is a string";
    if (lComObject is T)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }

}
```

Comment: That worked perfectly! Thank you. Just for curiosity, is it possible to do this with a regular parameter?

Comment: You might be able to do something like `lComObject.GetType()` and compare them (e.g. `Equals`, not `is`).

Comment: Yea that was my original thought, but it only returns the most base type, which in this case was "object" so the comparison didn't work. But i used "==" instead of Equals, not sure if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 1):

The way with a parameter is:

```
static bool CompareObjectType(Type t) {

    object lComObject = "this is a string";
    if (lComObject.GetType() == t)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
}   

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    CompareObjectType(typeof(string));
}
```